# Microsoft Cognitive Speech-to-Text Service --- Choose Microphone

Tags: microphone, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-api

I am using Microsoft Cognitive Speech-to-Text service (MicrophoneRecognitionClient). Seems it uses the default microphone of my PC. If I have multiple microphones on my machine, and I want to specify which microphone to use, is there any way I can set it in the SDK api? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The STT Windows SDK only supports accessing the default communication device. You can configure which device this is through the audio control panel.

Always happy to get feature requests at https://cognitive.uservoice.com/ which the teams review on a regular basis during planning